# Infinite time axis on schedule app

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a scheduling app which has a time axis along the top of the app. However this time axis is of fixed length. How do I make this infinite, so when the user scrolls left or right they just scroll further into the past or future??

Please see this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wupurew/edit?html,output) to see a basic example of the fixed length time axis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just implement something of infinite length/content to your DOM as your browser would then take infinite time to load it as well.

However, you can break your infinity down to several loading steps through AJAX.
So, as soon you reached the beginning or end of your timeline, AJAX loads older/newer events into it.

The jQuery method `.scrollLeft()` could help you to get the current horizontal scroll position.